# Solidity: call modifiers from other smart contracts

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Let's say I have a token smart contract with a bunch of functions and a modifier, and another crowdsale smart contract.
Referencing the token smart contract in my crowdsale smart contract allows me to call the token functions.
However... I cannot use the modifier from the token smart contract.

```
contract Crowdsale is Token {

    token private _token;

    constructor (ERC20 token) public {
        require(address(token) != address(0));

        _token = token;
    }

// this one works
    function test(address account) public view returns (uint256) {
        _token.functionFromToken(account);
    }

// This does not work because of modifierInToken
    function test2(address account) public modifierInToken {

    }

}
```

Is it normal? And if so, is there a workaround?

Comment: did you use inheritance ? can you show code?

Comment: @AbdullahAziz I just added a little code there, thanks for your help!

Comment: also show the code for token. Let me have a look on the modifier.

Comment: I don't think the code for the token really matters since the error is "Undeclared identifier". It seems like the modifier is strictly private while the reach of the functions can be set to public or whatever we want.

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is the following:
- In my token smart contract, I added an "intermediate" function. That function is directly called in the modifier from my token.
- In my crowdsale smart contract, I replicated the modifier, calling the intermediate function in it.

This way, whenever I want to update all my modifiers coming from my original smart contract, all I have to do is to edit the "intermediate" function.

The default of that approach is that the "intermediate function" needs to be set to public in order to be called from any other smart contract, so be careful is you're choosing that approach.